# asp.net now() function with different time zones

Tags: asp.net

I will be entering some values into a database based on input from users. One value will be the date and time of the input.

I'm not sure how this works at all, but a user from e.g. New York enters some data and the website is hosted in the UK...what time will be stored?

Up until now I had been using the "now()" function to record the date and time, but just occured to me that this could happen! What else should I use?

Thanks,

Comment: So just recording it as Date.UtcNow would work?

Comment: you can either save all dates in your storage as `UTC` or use proper type that includes time zone data, for example in SQL 2008 you can use `datetimeoffset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UTC`, works in any time zone, you can either save all dates in your storage as `UTC` or use proper type that includes time zone data, for example in SQL 2008 you can use `datetimeoffset`